# Docker Set Up mysql db

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I was setting up mysql with docker and I observe that without defining environment in docker-compose.xml, file I am able to run mysql . Is this good or I am going wrong ?

my **docker-compose.xml** is

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3302:3306"
```

and my **settings.py** file is

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': myproj,
        'USER': root,
        'PASSWORD': 123123123,
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

I didn't enter any environment in xml file . If even I do its working same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe I don't understand exactly what you want to do but this is how it works.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3302:3306"

...
```

.env file:

```
MYSQL_HOSTNAME=mysql_db
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123123123123123123
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=123123123
```

Here you can see which ones are possible. [Environment Variables-1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html) and [Environment Variables-2](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Comment: got it . just wanted to confirm 1 thing , My db is resetting again and again . Is that due to when I create new build ?

Comment: You can Persists the db Data in a Volume. `- "./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"`

Comment: thanks , do you have any complete guide link for django web to docker etc or helping material  ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have nothing for Django but you can use the Docker and Docker-Compose Documentation and you find many blogs and vids in your searchengine ;) By the way, if my answer helped you, you can mark it, but you do not need to :-)

Comment: hi kindly can you have a look here ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279528/mysql-is-not-connecting-docker/64279756#64279756