# Mysql is not connecting Docker

Tags: django, docker, gitlab

I am trying to connect mysql docker container on live server but Its not working

**My docker-compose file is**

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./app/app/.env
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
    - "3302:3306"
```

and **my env file is like**

```
MYSQL_PORT=3306 
MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

and **my Django settings.py is**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': mydb,
        'USER': root,
        'PASSWORD': root,
        'HOST': db,
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

and **error log on gitlab CI is**

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

Comment: Did you installed mysqlclient?

Comment: @ViLuWi  I think so , as its in  requirment.txt file  as   `mysqlclient==2.0.1`

Comment: Did you mean to specify port 3302? Is Django also running in a container or directly on the host?

Comment: @GregCowell  I have edited and added my full yml file . kindly have a look

Comment: You mention a CI setup and the log message says "test database"; is the `docker-compose.yml` file you show actually starting the application, or is something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze  I have included my   `.gitlab-ci.xml`  file kindly have  a look

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose file, you mapped the port 3306 to 3302.

*It means that your database is listening in 3306 (as configured in the environnement file), but from outside the container, this port is redirected to port 3302.*

Your Django should connect to your database on port **3302**, example "setting.py" is below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': mydb,
        'USER': root,
        'PASSWORD': root,
        'HOST': db,
        'PORT': 3302,
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly can you indicate where I need to change ?  by giving example please ?

Comment: I did this in  docker-compose    `ports: - "3306:3306"`  still not working

Comment: and what should be my  docker-compose file ? It can be same as I posted ?

Comment: Inter-container connections ignore `ports:`; you always connect to the standard port for the service (for MySQL, port 3306).

Comment: Can you access the MySql server from the host? So there where your Django App is! `mysql -u root -p -h db -P 3302 -D mydb`

Comment: @GregorWedlich   I am using gitlab-cli   so I dont know how I can access mysql from there

Comment: No, that is not what the Gitlab-Continius integration is for. Under Linux use ssh for debbuging.

Comment: Try running the docker-compose locally and check if you're able to connect to MySQL container. It might be a case where your Django container is trying to create a connection to the MySQL but the MySQL container has not yet spun up.